# How to reassign general confirm function from "Enter" key?

Tags: interface

i would like to reassign general confirm function from the "Enter: key to something else. My setup is setup in the way, that i cant reach right side of keyboard because it covered with my graphic tablet.

I reassigned most hotkeys i use to the left side of the keyboard, but i can't find how to reassign general confirm function from "Enter" to another key.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by going to *User Preferences > Input* and changing *Name* to *Key-binding* and typing the word `enter` into the text box.

[image: User Preferences Navigation]

Sadly you will have to change every single instance to your new command by hand unless someone else can come up with a script to do it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

In the input settings some are linked to the `Enter` key and some are linked to `Return`, but I am pretty sure that the general enter that you refer to is hard coded, meaning you will need to build your own patched version of blender to change it.

I would see if you can link a button on your tablet to the enter key, maybe by playing a macro. What system you are using will determine what options you have for that.

You could also try moving things around, maybe you could tilt the keyboard up and have the tablet in front of the keyboard instead of over it.